# Flashtext issue with loading many Chinese keywords

Tags: python

I am trying to upload a dictionary of Chinese words, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
In:'浙江帅丰电器股份有限公司' in dictionary2
Out: True

from flashtext import KeywordProcessor
processor = KeywordProcessor()
processor.add_keywords_from_dict(dictionary2)

In: '浙江帅丰电器股份有限公司' in processor
Out: False
```

The keywords don't reflect in the processor, not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What does `dictionary2` looks like ? [here](https://github.com/vi3k6i5/flashtext/blob/b316c7e9e54b6b4d078462b302a83db85f884a94/flashtext/keyword.py#L329) is the code of the function, which says what it should look like. Alternatively have you tried using the `add_keyword` function ?

Comment: It is just a dictionary that has Chinese phrases (str) as Keys and in Values there is English equivalent (list with str) so in theory should be ok and i don't get any error message

Comment: By using `add_keyword` you mean to add the keywords one by one in a loop?